# Jquery Tabs BeforeLoad not working with div on same page

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have two tabs on same page as shown below. I want to do some functionality before load of the perticular div but its not working.

```
<div id="tabs1">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Address</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Map here</p>
   </div>

   <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Address here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code is as below.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs1" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        alert("fas");
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo."
          );
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, all your tabs are "local" and no ajax call is triggered.

If you want to load a tab content using ajax, you should specify a remote href on your link :

```
<div id="tabs1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/ajax/map">Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ajax/address">Address</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Check the [example](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) in the documentation.